# Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2"

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a Powershell script that identifies users who haven't logged in for 90 days, but I keep getting this error message:

Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".  At first I thought it was a variable type mismatch but looking at the variables for subtraction it looks fine.

```
PS C:\> $today.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType

PS C:\> $users[198].LastLogonDate.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType
```

---

```
$today = Get-Date
$days = 90
$users = Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter *
foreach ($i in $users) 
{
    $difference = $today - $i.LastLogonDate
    #Write-Host $i.Name + $difference.Days
    if ($difference.Days -ge $days){Write-Host $i.name " hasn't logged on in 90 days"}
    elseif ($i.LastLogonDate -eq $null) {Write-Host $i.name " has null value"}
    else {Write-Host " No Value"}
}
```

Thoughts??

Thanks!!

Comment: Perhaps one of the entries in $users is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

You get the error for users who have never logged on. The **LastLogonDate** property is null, therefore you can't subtract it from $today. To prevent the error, check whether the property is null first, in an **if** statement, and only attempt the subtraction otherwise.

```
foreach ($i in $users) {
  if ($i.LastLogonDate -eq $null) {
    Write-Host $i.name " has null value"
  } else {
    $difference = $today - $i.LastLogonDate
    if ($difference.Days -ge $days) {
      Write-Host $i.name " hasn't logged on in 90 days"
    } else {
      Write-Host " No Value"
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, I'm not quite sure in which cases you intended to output the **" No Value"** message, but that's going to be displayed for any users who have logged on in the last 90 days.

Comment: @user2565554 The best way to acknowledge answers that help you is to accept/upvote them. Accept the answer that most answered your question by clicking the check mark mark to the left of the answer. Upvote answers that provided you with helpful information by clicking the up arrow above the number on the left. You can upvote multiple answers, including the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan "90" -UsersOnly
```

Comment: Much easier way to accomplish what I was trying to do! Thanks!